# Magento 2 : How to send contact form notifications to multiple recipients ?

Tags: magento2, contact-us

I would like to send contact from contents to multiple E-Mail recipients, I checked there is no options for comma separated email address same like orders,shipping etc.

how to do that ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with **Magento2** default installation. You will need to create a **custom module** that overrides the method **sendEmail()** from the **\vendor\magento\module-contact\Controller\Index\Post.php**:

```
private function sendEmail($post)
{
    $this->mail->send($post['email'], ['data' => new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($post)]);
}
```

As you can see by default it sends to only one email( the one you set in the admin panel). To create a custom module follow the video from [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/). And [here](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/) is a nice tutorial about overriding classes.

Comment: The value $post['email'] has the email introduced in the contact form not the one set up in the admin panel. $post['email'] It is only used to set a replyTo in the email

Comment: you cant override a private method.